# org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't acquire next trigger: Unknown column 'SCHED_TIME' in 'field list'

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

when i am trying to create a simple job scheduler with quartz and persistence as mysql i am getting the following error.

org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't acquire next trigger: Unknown column 'SCHED_TIME' in 'field list'

caused by

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'SCHED_TIME' in 'field list'

I checked thoroughly in the database schema provided by quartz official website. But i couldn't able to find any corresponding column.

Answer (score 0):

Add the field SCHED_TIME of type NUMBER(28) on the table QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS

Comment: according to the latest docs http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/migration-guide.html the correct change is `alter table qrtz_fired_triggers add column sched_time BIGINT(13) NOT NULL;`

Answer (score 0):

Its all about Quartz Scheduler version in maven dependency.

For the quartz version 2.2.0 and 2.1.7 there are modifications in the database schema with added fields like SCHED_TIME .

So, use 2.1.7 version of quartz maven dependency or find the proper database schema script for 2.2.0.

Note: I hope the database schema script for mysql provided in the source file of Quartz team is not proper with respect to Quartz 2.2.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

Add the field `SCHED_TIME` on the table QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS

```
run the sql query -->> alter table QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS add sched_time NUMBER(13);
```